# how to create a custom payment gateway with webpay plus in laravel?

Tags: laravel, shopify, payment-gateway

I created a webpay payment successfully but now what i want is to connect my webpay with shopify payment gateway, So i can get all the payments done via webpay plus.

Thank you In Advance

Answer (score 0):

To become a legal payment partner with Shopify. You need to implement the [Shopify payment APP](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/payments-apps).

Currently, this process is invite-only and not open to all.
You can check regarding the development and review process to become a [Shopify payment partner](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/payments#payments-app-approval-process) here.

[image]